# Failed to load requested resource : The requested url was not found on server - Xamarin forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am developing `Webview` in `xamarin.forms`. When I point code to Android its works fine but for iOS `Webview` is not displaying, blank screen coming. I am testing in `iPhone 8 plus simulator`.

This error coming

```
file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4DD56-0284-4C1B-BBB9-73448C67F0DA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/67EEDDD5-9CAB-47D8-8A6FAB9403E/Bite2.iOS.app/https:/service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js/
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server
```

This is my code

```
//getting html content from https url 
string content = LoadUATData();

var source = new HtmlWebViewSource()
{
    BaseUrl = "https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js",
    Html = content.Trim()
};

//public WebViewSource WebSource { get; set; } WebSource is getting assigned to WebView in UI
WebSource = source;
```

When I debug `Webview` `simulator` in `Safari`, I can see below error in `inspect`

[image]

This error showing in inspect element

[image]

This is info.plist file, new code I have added

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your data will be used to deliver personalized promotional offers to you.</string>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>.force.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </d ict>
        </dict>
</dict>
```

Please help me to fix this ?

Comment: `BaseUrl` is typically used when you are loading local HTML documents and want to specify relative paths.   If you are loading remote documents then I don't think you need to use `BaseUrl` at all

Answer (score 0):

As Json said , `BaseUrl` is typically used when you are loading `local HTML documents` and want to specify relative paths, so that the Webview would know where the `HTML` came from and use that to link other files.

In your scenario , you show html string directly on Webview , in this way `BaseUrl`  is unnecessary ,just remove it and try again .

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content.